# Writing custom Kafka SSLEngineFactory with arguments at runtime

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I am building kafka clients with SSL configuration. I want Kafka to get Truststore's keys from DB and not from jks file stored somewhere. So I implemented org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SslEngineFactory interface from which I can supply SSLEngines. SSLContext from which these SSL Engines are created,are initiated with my truststore(I have written code to get keys from DB).

```
props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
props.put("ssl.engine.factory.class", CustomSslEngineFactory.class);
```

This configuration works well.
Now, I want to enable client auth to SSL, which means I need to supply keystore to SSLContext. But which keystore to use is decided at runtime.(This is my requirement). I cannot add it to CustomSslEngineFactory because I dont know which keystore to add.
CustomSslEngineFactory object is created by Kafka and it will not be having access to any run time parameters. So how can we send some parameters to CustomSslEngineFactory at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom `SslEngineFactory` implementation you had to override the configure method:

```
void configure(Map<String, ?> configs);
```

Kafka client will pass all of its properties into this method before calling the method to create the SSL engine so you can add any custom property you want when creating Kafka properties, read them in the configure method and use them in the methods to create the SSL engine.

Something like this in Kotlin:

```
class ScalerKafkaSslEngineFactory : SslEngineFactory {

    private var sslContext: SSLContext? = null
    private lateinit var keyStore: KeyStore

    override fun configure(configs: Map<String?, *>) {
        keyStore = configs["my.ssl.keystore"] as KeyStore
    }

    override fun createClientSslEngine(peerHost: String, peerPort: Int, endpointIdentification: String): SSLEngine? {
        return createSslEngine(Mode.CLIENT, peerHost, peerPort)
    }

    override fun createServerSslEngine(peerHost: String, peerPort: Int): SSLEngine? {
        return createSslEngine(Mode.SERVER, peerHost, peerPort)
    }

    private fun createSslEngine(mode: Mode, peerHost: String, peerPort: Int): SSLEngine? {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault()
        // set my keyStore
        return sslContext.createSSLEngine(peerHost, peerPort)
    }

    override fun close() {
        sslContext = null
    }
    
    // other methods from interface skipped
}
```